# Flutter Route<T> recall didChangeNext if the state of the next Route has changed

Tags: flutter, callback, state

In Flutter `Route<T>`, we can get information about the next route using the function `didChangeNext`.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Route-class.html

This can be useful to get properties of the next route such as its transition. These properties can then be used to modify the outgoing routes transition to match. But what if the next route changes its state for any reason? `didChangeNext()` will not be called again just because the internalState of the next route changed.

For context, I have added a setter to allow the next route to change its transition. If the route is then popped, this transition is only reflected on the route where this property was changed and not the previous Route as `didChangeNext` is only called if the actual route of the next Route changes.

How can we monitor state changes of the nextRoute from `didChangeNext`.